# Занос значения чекбоксов в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Кто нибудь может это сделать?

В общем в mysql мне надо занести значения $mas

```
     $id = $_POST['id_parent'];
       $mas = ( $_POST['sold'] );
      $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO parent(id, children, children1, children2, children3, children4)
VALUES ('$id')");
```

Comment: Жесть.
А почему не использовать только одно поле в таблице? 
Туда записывать массив со значениями, можно даже юзать сериализованный массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не помешало бы более корректно задать вопрос, но если у вас приходит массив (*$_POST['sold']*) и его надо соответственно распределить в поля children, children1, children2, childrenN, то можете сделать и так:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO parent(id, children, children1, children2, children3, children4) VALUES ('$id', '$mass[0]', '$mass[1]', '$mass[2]', '$mass[3]', '$mass[4]')");
```